# Is it possible to duplicate an iOS application without duplicating all the code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have 3 applications that share a lot of functionality. It is only the content and styling changes between them.

Instead of simply duplicating the project for each app, is there a way to make a "base" application and then have the 3 applications extend this?

Simply duplicating the project would be horrible to maintain, whereas extending a "base" would allow them to all update simultaneously.

I know you could create the project and then copy all files from the old project into the new. This would keep the files up-to-date, however if any files were added or removed, you would have to manually do that.

Comment: how about achieving this through the revision control, i think it is doable via git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have one base project that uses multiple targets.  Each target can include a subset of the files in your main project, and/or add their own independent files.  Each target can also have its own set of preprocessor defines set up in the build configuration.

Comment: Also, each target can (and should) use a different info.plist file to distinguish it's name, bundle identifier, etc.

Comment: Also each target should get a preprocessor macros, then in your code you can go #ifdef MYMACROFORTARGETONE and that code will be specific to that target.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more targets to your project in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Create a project that builds a static library for the reusable components. You can use an Aggregate target to package any associated resources, such as nib files, storyboards, images, etc.

Your app projects can all then consume the static library and resources. Any changes to the static library will be available to all the dependent projects.